# TortoiseSVN on Windows 10: only "unmodified" status icons in Explorer

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Since upgrading my Windows 7 Professional to Windows 10, TortoiseSVN (64bit) only shows the "unmodified" icons on files. The problem ist **not** that others disapper, the problem is, that **even for modified** files and folders the "unmodified" icon shows up.

```
tortoiseproc /command:rebuildiconcache
```

doesn't help. Neither does rebooting.
the TSVNCache-process is running.
Overlay-icon settings are set to "Default"

Uninstalling, rebooting, reinstalling, rebooting helped at my computer at home. There I see that the modified icon does not show up. 
Under 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers I can see 8 Items from ownCloud and right after that the 9 TortoiseSVN-entries. Which tells me that they should all be visible apart from the last one, which is the "unversioned" entry.

Any hints as to where to look or what to do? The attached screenshot was taken after uninstalling TortoiseSVN, rebooting, installing 1.9.2.26806-x64 and rebooting again

Here is a Screenshot of TortoiseSVN settings, explorer window, commit window and registry:

[image: Screenshot of TortoiseSVN settings, explorer window, commit window and registry]

Cheers
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Windows has an ugly limit of only allowing 15 overlay icons. If you have more registered Windows will not display some overlay icons. So delete some overlay icons under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers` of ownCloud, Onedrive until you are under the limit.

Comment: As noted, I do have more than 15 icons registered, but the first 15 include the "modified" icon of TortoiseSVN. And the point is: The modified files at work do show an icon. But it's the wrong one. At home, as stated, I have 16 icons and the "unversioned" icon should not display, with which I'd be fine, if only the others showed up.

Comment: I have no idea how Windows decides which overlay icons it uses if more than 15 are installed.

Comment: The icons are processed in alphabetical order. That's why many vendors start to outrival each other by using more and more spaces in front of the key names...